# How to submit WordPress project with plugins and widgets?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, project-management

In a WordPress project I use widgets and plugins a lot. After completing a project, which folders should I submit to client (project folder with plugins and widgets)?

1. Only project folders?
2. Project folder and plugin folder?

Comment: It entirely depends on what your client is expecting. What have you arranged with them? Is there a contract or project brief? Also are the plugins free or paid for?

Comment: That was a contract or wordpress theme development. I have used free widgets and free plugins to develop the theme. Now how will I submit it to client with plugins and widgets? Actually I want to know which folders should I submit?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably send the whole `/wp-content` folder of your test installation, or whatever your environment looks like. As you might know there are subfolders for plugins, themes and uploads. That is what your client needs.

If you want to transfer content, finished pages and more, you need to export the database, too. That is what is described in ["Moving WordPress"](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress).

Comment: Further more, depending on what your contract stipulates, you may want to include any source files such PSDs etc. Technically speaking if you're contracted to build a theme you only need to supply the theme folder; but if it's dependant on third-party plugins yo should supply those also. In future I'd be wary of making your theme dependant on third-party plugins; you end up in murky territory regarding updates and support for a plugin you didn't write.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Try to reduce the use of external plugins for the themes core functions to a minium. This will save you and your clients lots of trouble in case a plugin changes or is discontinued.